# Why getting this error :Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I am using this code to open crystal report in VS2010 ,`axCRViewer1` is `crystal report viewer control name` , but getting error at this line

`axCRViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;`

How do I fix it ?

```
private void ViewR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                DataSetPatient ds = new DataSetPatient(); // .xsd file name
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                DataTable dt = DBHandling.GetPatient();//getting data using GetPatient()

                // Just set the name of data table
                dt.TableName = "Crystal Report P";
                ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

                // Your .rpt file path will be below
                rptDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\Monika\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SonoRepo\\SonoRepo\\Reports\\CrystalReportP.rpt");

                //set dataset to the report viewer.
                rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
                axCRViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;//getting error at this line 
                // code to get data from the DB           
            }
```

**Getpatient() Code**

```
public static DataTable GetPatient()
        {
            DataTable patientTable = new DataTable();
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=sonorepo.mdb"))
            {
                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT PatientID,PFirstName FROM Patient_Registration", con))
                    da.Fill(patientTable);
            }
            return patientTable;
        }
```

Comment: What is the type expected by `axCRViewer1.ReportSource` , use '(explicit cast)rptDoc' for that type and try.

Comment: Maybe this is related to your issue http://scn.sap.com/message/14127240

Answer (score 0):

This message is coming from the data. Check if the structure of DataTable dt is the same as the structure of the first table in DataSetPatient.

You can also try to replace the code for DataSetPatient.

DataSetPatient ds = new DataSetPatient(); // .xsd file name
....
ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

with

DataSet ds = new Dataset()
ds.Tables.Add

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

If you are installing on a 64-bit machine, make sure the application properties under the Build tab have "Any CPU" as the platform target, and unselect the check box for "Prefer 32-bit" if you have the option. Crystal is very touchy about 32/64 bit assemblies, and makes some pretty counterintuitive assumptions which are very difficult to troubleshoot.